# How to prove that $U(20)$ and $U(24)$ are not isomorphic?

Tags: group-theory

$U(20)$ and $U(24)$ are both the same order.  How would I prove that these groups are not isomorphic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a hint: every element of $U(24)$ has order $2$, while $U(20)$ has a handful of elements of order $4$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.  I know that for two groups G and H to be isomorphic each group must have a subgroup of the same order.  The cyclic subgroup generated by some element of order n in U(20), where n does not equal 2, will be of order n.  Thus, U(24) and U(20) are not isomorphic.

Comment: Good!! Specifically, the cyclic subgroup generated by $3 \in U(20)$ is of size four; this will never happen for any element in $U(24)$.